# Where do I read data from UART?

Tags: uart

In my EFM32LG controller I receive UART data from PORT C pin 1 as shown in the table below, which is taken from EFM32LG data sheet. I would like to read the whole byte and decide what LED to blink depending on the received byte.

Where can I see the whole received byte?

The data sheet is available [here](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm32lg-datasheet.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the first byte of the received data from from the `USARTn_RXDATA` register. The registers and functionality of the USART unit are described starting on page 447 of this [reference manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf). You can also learn more about programming the EFM32 from the Silabs [getting started guide](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an0009.0-efm32-ezr32-series-0-getting-started.pdf).

I am not familiar with the EFM32, but from the datasheet it would look something like this:

```c
uint8_t read_byte = USART0->RXDATA;
```

It is important that you enable the USART receiver first by setting the `RXEN` bit.

```c
USART0->CMD = USART0->CMD | (1 << RXEN);
```