# what is the exact address of parity property

Tags: embedded, registry

the tables shown bellow are taken from efm32LG reference manual
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf
i Have the main base address of 0x4000C000 inside of which i have with 0x004 offset the usartn_frame regesiter and in the 8th 9th place i have my parity properties.
What should i do with all three of those numbers in order to get the whole address to accsess the parity property ?
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The address is just the base address plus offset.  Are you trying to figure out how to write  code (.e.g in C) to modify it?

Comment: @rocko445 UART communication is done successfully as per this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683711/where-do-i-read-data-from-uart. It implies some where in the initialization part UART is configured where you can see how parity is configured.

Comment: Hello,so the parity bits are located at
0x4000C000+0x004+0x8=0x4000C004+0x8=0x4000C00C

0x4000C000+0x004+0x8=0x4000C004+0x9=0x4000C00D
?